# Covariance inequality to yield a metric space

Tags: probability, inequality, metric-spaces, covariance

Suppose $X,Y,Z$ are real-valued random variables, with non-negative covariances:
$$
\text{Cov}(X,Y),\text{Cov}(Y,Z),\text{Cov}(X,Z)\geq0.
$$
Is it true that
$$
\text{Var}(X-Y)+\text{Var}(Y-Z)\geq \text{Var}(X-Z)?
$$
If this inequality is true then it has a nice consequence: $\text{Var}(X-Y)$ defines a metric (on a space of random variables with non-negative covariances).

*It feels like, if this inequality is true, there must be a simple proof. However I am struggling. So far I have only managed to find an equivalent inequality:
$$
\text{Cov}(X,Z)+\text{Var}(Y)\geq \text{Cov}(X,Y)+\text{Cov}(Y,Z).
$$
Any thoughts much appreciated.*

Answer (score 1):

The inequality is false. Here is a counter-example. Consider independent real-valued random variables $U,V$, with $\text{Var}(U)\geq\text{Var}(V)>0$; and set $Y=U$, $X=U+V$, $Z=U-V$.

Then the pairs of $X,Y,Z$ see positive covariances. Meanwhile
$$
\text{Var}(X-Y)+\text{Var}(Y-Z)=2\text{Var}(V)<4\text{Var}(V)=\text{Var}(Z-X).
$$